# Importing .bacpac to SQL Azure via Azure Resource Manager from public blob

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I created a .bacpac from the original SQL Azure DB I want to import to a new database during my deployment process. To do this, I want to have a github page with the usual Deploy to Azure button, that in as close to one click performs the deployment task, and sets up my entire application.

To do this, however, I need to set up some initial data on the database. After consulting the internet, I saw the post [Using Azure Resource Manager to Copy Azure SQL Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360148/using-azure-resource-manager-to-copy-azure-sql-databases), which had a similar issue.

Right now, I have a MSDeploy extension running in the ARM template that deploys a website from a public azure blob. I'd ideally like to do this with the database too, but the command seems to *require* storageKeyType and storageKey parameters to be filled.

Is there any way to go around this limitation? Should I just give up and have my application perform the initial setup of the database? Sharing the storage key in a public github template does not seem like a very good plan!

Here's a code snippet:

```
"resources": [
        {
          "name": "Import",
          "type": "extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('sqlsrvmymisName')]",
            "[variables('sqldbmymisName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "storageUri": "https://publicblob.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/publicblob.bacpac",
            "administratorLogin": "MasterAccount",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "P@ssw0rd",
            "operationMode": "Import",
            "storageKeyType": "Primary",
            "storageKey": ""
          }
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want it to be public, try this:

```
"storageKeyType": "SharedAccessKey",
"storageKey": "?",
```

Comment: Thank you, it loaded correctly. Now to figure out if it works for our purposes!